# android project contains error (eclipse) but not visible

Tags: android, eclipse

I have checked out a project in eclipse, though it had some compilation error, like missing libraries. I fixed it. Now I can't see any error remaining in whole project, but still there is a red mark over project folder. which is keeping me from compiling the project. I know it is hard to suggest solution this way, but i couldn't find any thing relavent that I could post. You guys might have gone through this error plz help. 
(I am using eclipse juno, project is on 4.1 google api).

edit: may be this could help. But I why this is a problem, bcz I these 3 are the version are in library projects.

```
 [2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] Versions found are:
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] Path: C:\Users\Ankit\workspace\workspace-android\FacebookSDK\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ]    Length: 349252
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ]    SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] Path: C:\Users\Ankit\workspace\workspace-android\HealthCity\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ]    Length: 271754
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ]    SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] Path: C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\SlidingMenu-master\library\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ]    Length: 385685
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ]    SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-07-11 17:26:49 - ] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: Is that red mark a exclamation sign?

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild, if you haven't already.

Comment: clean & build didn't solve my problem. also I have checked in libraries there is no missing reference also.

Comment: Try restarting eclipse

Comment: I have had eclipse go really weird on me before. This sounds crazy but try deleting (highlight and hit the delete key) all the problems in the "problems" view.

Comment: @KenWolf OMG, i didn't expected this, but it worked :P

Comment: Great! I think sometimes Eclipse just gets confused, poor thing. :) I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long shot - I have had Eclipse go really weird on me before where it just sort of gets "stuck".

This may sound crazy but to fix it try deleting (highlight and hit the delete key) all the problems in the "problems" view.

This basically clears your problems. Don't worry, the next time you build/launch the project if there are real problems they will come up again so there's no real harm in doing it.

Comment: did not he say he had none? what is there to delete, the whole project?

Comment: @BorisGafurov he says he "can't see any error remaining in whole project, but still there is a red mark over project folder". This indicates to me that there will be a problem in the problems view and that is what I am advising him to delete. Not the whole project. He does not specifically say he has no problems in the problems view, merely that he found no errors remaining in his project. He also replied that this fixed his problem and this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem while working with the `facebook-sdk`. you simply can fix your issue, in deleting two of your `android-support-v4.jars` and replace the deleted ones with the third one.

I guess this problem occurs, because the different projects contains 'optimized' support-libraries, which are compiled within the projects. In the end, all three libraries are the same but might not offer all the same functionality (correct me if I am wrong?!).

Comment: could this be possibly bcz of proguard ?

Comment: i really cannot tell. I was forced to work with `javascript` a lot, and there you can optimize libraries like `mootools` or 'jquery' by only including functions you need... Maybe you can do something similar in Android-Library-Projects?!

Answer (score 0):

I opened Build Path of Project and in that checked libraries I wanted. That resolved my problem. When you compile you might getting Pop-Up in which error is shown. Are you able to see such window ?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project first.

Check for the problems in the build path. [This](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaViews) link would be helpful for resolving such issues.